# EmberJS trigger computed property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Suppose I have the following computed property;

```
someCP: function() {

}.property(obj.innerObj.attr)
```

My question is will this get triggered even if obj.innerObj does not have 'attr' defined ?

How does this CP work?

Comment: The dependent key of the computed property isn't a string, is that on purpose? What do you mean by "triggered"? The cache won't invalidate, because `attr` doesn't exist and thus doesn't get updated.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

First, as already mentioned in comments, dependent key should be a string:

```
someCP: function() {

}.property('obj.innerObj.attr')
```

Also, this code may be rewriten to:

```
someCP: Ember.computed('obj.innerObj.attr', function() {

})
```

First form is not guarantied to work.

As for the "triggering", Ember should compute property when it's used for the frist time, than cache it and re-compute when dependent property changed. In your case it's never. However I'm not sure how it will work in practice, but in theory it should work in this way.

Comment: Why do you say the First form is not guarantied to work ?

Comment: @testndtv It can be disabled via configuration. It's not critical if you are controlling the whole codebase and environment. You can find an explanation [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html) and [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.6.0/configuring-ember/disabling-prototype-extensions/)